# Using Aggregate to rename a field in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

Working on query to rename field 'expertise' to skills, expertise is an array which holds more than one so looking to slice it to 1.
Example of table:{ "_id" : "E08", "name" : "Damien Collins", "expertise" : [ "Python", "Java" ] }

Looking to show named, expertise as "skill" and just to show one piece of expertise.

Current query:

```
db.employees.aggregate([{expertise:{$exists:true}},{$project:{_id:1,"Skill":{expertise{$slice:1}},name:1}}])
```

Had it working before the rename of skill part.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return 1 element of the array:

```
{$project:{_id:1,"Skill":{$arrayElemAt:["$expertise",0]},name:1}}
```